# use final inside a for each loop

Tags: java, final

I have a small conflict with effective java. On one hand it strongly encourages to use final modifier. It also encourages to use foreach loop.

However I did not see any piece of code anywhere, which codes like this:

```
for (final element e : list) {
  // do whatever.
}
```

If element is not expected to change then using final appears to be good. Why is it not so common?

Comment: I use it all the time. Others don't use it because they say it 'clutters the code'. This type of loop is called an 'Enhanced for-loop'.

Comment: I use it all the time too. But I tend to agree with both the camps. If you really don't want a reference to be re-assigned, use `final`, period. But it actually *does* clutter the code a lot. I have seen large chunks of code written in a *good* way but unfortunately looks overly verbose. Unfortunately there is no simple which can please both the camps, unless of course you are ready to move to Scala... ;)

Answer (score 9):

Usually developers leave the defaults and only add code when they need to.  i.e. what ever is the shortest code to write is easier.  Think of a lecture theatre and they ask you to raise your hands if you do something and then they ask you to raise your hands if you don't, about half the room won't vote at all.

IMHO The default should have been final and you would have a keyword `var` for values which can change.  This way much more fields would be final.

In this particular case, I don't make local variables final on the basis that methods should be short enough that you can reason whether the variable is changed or not. If you can't easily work this out, your loop/method is too complicated.

For fields however, I do recommend making these final whenever possible, esp if they are not private, as it is not so easy to read all the code where it might be used.

Answer (score 6):

It's not used because its "code noise".

The final keyword should be used for all method parameters, etc etc, but it's not, because while more "correct", it's less readable.

Answer (score 3):

There are many places where you could - some say should - place the final keyword. A common example is method parameters. Look at this snippets of code:

```
public static long pow_mod(final long base, final long exponent, final long mod) {
    // body
}
```

There is another convention to break lines of code after 80 characters. This declaration is not even indented yet (it has to be inside a class) and it is already longer than that amount. Java is a very verbose language, there is no need to clutter your code even more; especially since there is nothing to be gained making local variables final.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the element would be final inside the scope of the for-loop. Not much to be gained there.

Comment: It's quite useful in the case of a `Runnable`, and it helps to prevent logic errors caused by overwriting the wrong variable.

Comment: especially in the case where the 'final' variable is being used within the 'for-each' loop as the key in accessing a collection which can be written to at the same time in a different thread.